# Getting the next element of a list in JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I am programming a small game that uses a grid of tiles with specific colours. The colours are stored in an array. How can I implement that the colour of the tile switches if the user clicks on it? Is there a way I can interate "infinetly" through the array, or is there a better option?

Comment: What do you mean by switching the color? Do you mean by swapping the color with an adjacent tile? Can you elaborate `iterate "infinitely" through the array` ?

Comment: @user3437460 The tile should change its colour to the next one in an already predefined array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I implement that the colour of the tile switches if the user clicks on it? Is there a way I can interate "infinetly" through the array, or is there a better option?

If you mean by cycling through a series of predefined colours when the tile is clicked. This is what you can do:

```
//Example
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};
int idx = 0;    

//on click, perform the following
tile.setColor(colors[(idx+1)%colors.length]);
```

Mod the incremented colour index ensures colour cycling.

You can apply the same logic in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be for your Tile class to contain a static array of colors, and an instance variable that indicates the index of the color of that instance.

Then the action listener for clicking on a Tile instance would retrieve the color index of that tile, increment the index (with proper mod wrapping), and set the color of the tile to the new index.